# PHP Syntax Error, cannot understand what is wrong

Tags: php, syntax

Using the syntax below I get an error with this line of code. However if I change the line of code from an `elseif`statement to an `if` statement I don't get an error. What is wrong?

Error line: `elseif($weight  <= 5000)`

All of my PHP Code:

```
if ($delivery == 'one') {
if ($weight <= 1000) 
{
            if (royal_s) {
                $first    = 'Royal Mail Small Parcels';
                $first_p  = '3.00';
                $second   = 'Parcelforce 24';
                $second_p = '15.96';
            } elseif (royal_m) {
                $first    = 'Royal Mail Medium Parcels';
                $first_p  = '5.65';
                $second   = 'Parcelforce 24';
                $second_p = '15.96';
            } elseif (parcelforce) {
                $first    = 'Parcelforce 24';   
                $first_p  = '15.96';
            } else {
                sorry;
            }
} 
elseif ($weight  <= 2000) 
{
            if (royal_s){
                $first    = 'Royal Mail Small Parcels';
                $first_p  = '6.85';
                $second   = 'Parcelforce 24';
                $second_p = '15.96';
            } elseif(royal_m) {
                $first    = 'Royal Mail Medium Parcels';
                $first_p  = '8.90';
                $second   = 'Parcelforce 24';
                $second_p = '15.96';
            }
            elseif(parcelforce){
                $first    = 'Parcelforce 24';   
                $first_p  = '15.96';
            } else {
                sorry;
} 
elseif($weight  <= 5000) 
{
            if (royal_m) {
                $first    = 'Royal Mail Medium Parcels';
                $first_p  = '15.10';
                $second   = 'Parcelforce 24';
                $second_p = '16.92';
            } elseif(parcelforce){
                $first    = 'Parcelforce 24';   
                $first_p  = '15.96';
            } else {
                sorry;
            }
}
}
}
```

Comment: I'd say it would help if you indent every `if` block - the outermost one is not indented, and that makes it harder to read. Also, apply a brace style (same line or following line) consistently. Lastly if you post pseudo-code, do mention that fact - of course any PHP using variables without a dollar prefix (e.g. `royal_s`) will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bracket is at the wrong place:

```
 if ($delivery == 'one') {
    if ($weight <= 1000) 
    {
                if (royal_s) {
                    $first    = 'Royal Mail Small Parcels';
                    $first_p  = '3.00';
                    $second   = 'Parcelforce 24';
                    $second_p = '15.96';
                } elseif (royal_m) {
                    $first    = 'Royal Mail Medium Parcels';
                    $first_p  = '5.65';
                    $second   = 'Parcelforce 24';
                    $second_p = '15.96';
                } elseif (parcelforce) {
                    $first    = 'Parcelforce 24';   
                    $first_p  = '15.96';
                } else {
                    sorry;
                }
    } 
    elseif ($weight  <= 2000) 
    {
                if (royal_s){
                    $first    = 'Royal Mail Small Parcels';
                    $first_p  = '6.85';
                    $second   = 'Parcelforce 24';
                    $second_p = '15.96';
                } elseif(royal_m) {
                    $first    = 'Royal Mail Medium Parcels';
                    $first_p  = '8.90';
                    $second   = 'Parcelforce 24';
                    $second_p = '15.96';
                }
                elseif(parcelforce){
                    $first    = 'Parcelforce 24';   
                    $first_p  = '15.96';
                } else {
                    sorry;
    } 
}
    elseif($weight  <= 5000) 
    {
                if (royal_m) {
                    $first    = 'Royal Mail Medium Parcels';
                    $first_p  = '15.10';
                    $second   = 'Parcelforce 24';
                    $second_p = '16.92';
                } elseif(parcelforce){
                    $first    = 'Parcelforce 24';   
                    $first_p  = '15.96';
                } else {
                    sorry;
                }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly! I didn't spot the error.

Comment: The 'sorry' is a php function that I have defined. Tib was right that I needed to place an extra bracket before the elseif statement <=5000 and remove a bracket at the bottom of the script.